# How to fix Mongodb error "Could not read private key attached to the selected certificate" when I try to enable net.tls.certificateSelector

Tags: mongodb

Good day all. I am trying to configure Mongodb Server to use the local certificate store. However, I get the error:

```
Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration: Could not read private key attached to the selected certificate, ensure it exists and check the private key permissions
```

when I restart the error. I am using the following in my mongod.cfg

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, <IP Address>

  tls:
    mode: preferTLS
    certificateSelector: subject=<FQDN of Server>
```

I am using windows and requested a certificate from my company's CA using the Certificates snap in. Is there a special configuration needed for the certificate? Would a certificate generated from a windows certification server come with a passphrase? If so, how do I know what it is and specify it in the mongod.cfg file?

Comment: solved??? Please post the solution thanks, Im facing the same issue here